# Vibration effect on ipod

Tags: iphone

How to make vibration effect in ipod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [System Sound Services reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) at Apple's documentation:

> Vibration is available only on the iPhone.

and

> On the iPhone, you can pass the `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` constant to invoke vibration. **On an iPod touch, calling this function with that constant does nothing.**

So no, you can't program an iPod touch to vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

The iPod Touch doesn't have a vibration motor. It's impossible to make the iPod Touch vibrate.